# MongoDB to AWS S3: MongoServerError: not authorized: missing privilege for action outToS3 on resource __cluster__

Tags: javascript, mongodb, amazon-s3, cron, etl

I am trying to export data in my MongoDB Atlas Database into a .csv within AWS S3. I am having issues when following these references that seem to be out of date:

- https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/automated-continuous-data-copying-from-mongodb-to-s3/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atsTN9ee5pk

When I run .aggregate within either of them I get the following output:

```
 MongoServerError: not authorized: missing privilege for action outToS3 on resource __cluster__
```

It seems that my user cannot execute $out ?

Once I have the data being exported into my S3 I would like for this export to regularly via a MongoDB Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to output documents into an S3 bucket the MongoDB user must have the atlasAdmin privilege. I had your same problem and for me this was the solution.

It is not mentioned in the resources you linked (also the one I followed :)

Se docs here
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/supported-unsupported/pipeline/out/#permissions-required